# Проверка записи номера телефона и электроной почты

Tags: python

Написать функцию, которая на вход принимает строку, а на выход выдает булево значение (True или False), которое истинно, если полученная строка соответствует номеру телефона или адресу электронной почты.

```
import re
def check_string(string):
    if re.match(r'[\+7|8]?.?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{2}).?(\d{2})',string) and len(string) <=11 or re.match(r'^\w+[\.]?(\w+)*\@(\w+\.)*\w{2,}$',string):
        return(bool(string))
    else: return(False)   
print(check_string(input()))
```

Вот код который справляется с почтой, но почти справляется с телефонами. Например если телефон записать с 9 (9231231212), то его длина должна быть 10 цифр, а если с 8 (89231231212), то 11, с +7 соответственно длина 12. Но если написать номер с 9 и он будет длиной 11 символов, то номер оказывается верным, а должен выводится Folse. Как ограничить длину номера, относительно его начала? (помимо знака + в телефоне могут быть скобки и тире)

Вот список номеров которые должны быть правильные: +79160000000; 9160000000; 8(916)000-00-00; +7(916)000-00-00; (916)000-00-00; 8 (916) 000-00-00; +7 (916) 000-00-00; (916) 000-00-00; 8(916)0000000; +7(916)0000000; (916)0000000; 8-916-000-00-00; +7-916-000-00-00; 916-000-00-00;
номер -7 (910) 000-10-10 должен быть неправильный

Comment: +79160000000;

9160000000;

8(916)000-00-00;

+7(916)000-00-00;

(916)000-00-00;

8 (916) 000-00-00;

+7 (916) 000-00-00;

(916) 000-00-00;

8(916)0000000;

+7(916)0000000;

(916)0000000;

8-916-000-00-00;

+7-916-000-00-00;

916-000-00-00;

Comment: `(916) 000-00-00` Вот этот телефон должен определяться как правильный или нет?

Comment: @namerek как правильный

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, удалось разобраться с телефонными номерами?
Пробовала делать вот так:
if re.match(r'[\+7|8]?.?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{2}).?(\d{2})',string) and len(string) <=11
и вот так: re.match(r'^[78]?\d{10}$', string)
Что-то никак...

Comment: @Оля создайте отдельный вопрос. Покажите какие данные идут на вход и как вы пытались использовать приведенные Вами выражения. Так будет проще Вам помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите, такой результат нужен?

```py
import re

phones_str = str('+79160000000; 9160000000; 8(916)000-00-00; +7(916)000-00-00; (916)000-00-00; '
                 '8 (916) 000-00-00; +7 (916) 000-00-00; '
                 '(916) 000-00-00; 8(916)0000000; '
                 '+7(916)0000000; (916)0000000; 8-916-000-00-00; +7-916-000-00-00; 916-000-00-00')

phones = re.split(r' *; *', phones_str, flags=re.M)


def check_phone(num: str):
    clear_phone = re.sub(r'\D', '', num)
    result = re.match(r'^[78]?\d{10}$', clear_phone)
    print(bool(result))


for phone in phones:
    check_phone(phone)
```

Comment: Похоже на правду, только осталось разобраться в чём я ошибся) Спасибо

Comment: я так начал делать, потому что у меня ещё может почта вводится, а если я строку очищу от не цифр, то почта не будет выводится

Comment: у меня получилось связать с почтой) но теперь есть ошибка, если номер начинается с -7, а не с +7

Comment: -7 (916) 000-11-11 должно быть folse

Comment: @krumlyakov и если не сложно то всю строку с записью этого номера приведите пожалуйста

Comment: if re.match(r'^[78]?\d{10}$',clear_phone) or re.match(r'^\w+[\.]?(\w+)*\@(\w+\.)*\w{2,}$',string):

Comment: не понял какую строку)

Answer (score 0):

Вот код к решению этой задачи.

```
import re
def check_string(string):
    phone = re.sub(r'\b\D', '', string)
    clear_phone = re.sub(r'[\ \(]?', '', phone)
    if re.findall(r'^[\+7|8]*?\d{10}$', clear_phone) or re.match(r'^\w+[\.]?(\w+)*\@(\w+\.)*\w{2,}$',string):
        return(bool(string))
    else: return(False)   
print(check_string(input()))
```

Сначала очищаем номер от всех знаков препинания, кроме первого знака, после убираем лишние пробелы и скобки, если номер ими разделён, дальше делаем по шаблону начиная с +7 или 8

Comment: У меня для Вас 2 совета и один вопрос, если позволите. Для email используйте вот такое выражение `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,63}?@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{2,63}\.[a-zA-Z]+` поскольку шаблон `\w` не включает знак `-` и `.` . `\b\D` поймает любую НЕ цифру в начале слова (читайте телефона)  если на конце телефона случится (к примеру) пробел, то это он проскочит дальше. Теперь вопрос. Почему Вы решили оставить + в начале телефона. Для чего он Вам понадобился?

Comment: @Namerek + в начале телефона остаётся, потому что есть запись телефона такого типа: +7 999 99 99, если мы его убираем со всеми знаками, то запись -7 999 99 99 становится верной

Comment: Ну хозяин - барин. Начнутся неправильные срабатывания, пишите.

Comment: И раз уж Вы со мной согласились, позвольте еще один совет. Делайте проверку email адресов на наличие кириллицы если хотите потом их использовать для рассылки. Из практики - на 1000 адресов, обязательно найдется пара куда каким-то образом заскочили буквы кириллицы.